# Fetch data for each item of array

Tags: nuxt.js

I've blogposts that have a **"content"** array. In this array are an ID (asin) of a product and the content listed. For each item I want to make an api-call with the **asin-id** and show the specific product.

For testing I created a method `getProduct(content.asin)`, but of course that's not the solution. For each loop I want to show only the specific product and I don't want to click a button to load the data, I want the data to be fetched automatically. How can I do this?

**For visualisation:** Content Array (blogPost.content)

`content: [{ content: "some text", asin: "asinID" }, ...]`

**HTML**

```html
<div v-for="content in blogPost.content" :key="content.id">
  {{ content.asin }}

  <button @click="getProduct(content.asin)">Click</button>

  {{ product }}

  <div v-html="content.content"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      blogPost: [],
      product: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    try {
      const blogPost = await this.$axios.$get(
        `/api/get-post/${this.$route.params.id}`
      )
      this.blogPost = blogPost
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getProduct(asin) {
      try {
        const product = await this.$axios.$get('/api/get-product-from-asin', {
          params: { asin },
        })
        this.product = product
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over your blogPost content and make a http call for each item.
But it's not efficient, API should have the data in the main call.

But you can do:

```
blogPost.content.map((content) => {
   content.product = await this.$axios.$get('/api/get-product-from-asin', 
    {
      params: { content.asin },
    });
    return content;
});
```

Now blogPost content should contain your product data.